# Move billboardjs subchart on top of chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, billboard.js

Using the subchart options for billboardjs like in [the documentation](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#Interaction.SubChart) works as expected. 
What I want to know is:
Is there a way to show the subchart on top of the chart?
How should I proceed to make this happen?

Example from docs:

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
 ["sample", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
    ]
  },
  size:{width: 500, height: 250},
  subchart: {
    show: true
  },
  bindto: "#SubChart"
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css" />
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="SubChart"></div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are right, my answer doesn't work.  I'm going to delete it as I'm out of ideas...